# angularjs $filter how to filter 2d array

Tags: angularjs, filter

```
$scope.searchPo = function (id) {
       var match = $filter('filter')($scope.array, {po: id});
       return match;
});

$scope.array = 
[[{"po":1},{"po":2},{"po":3}],
[{"po":11},{"po":12},{"po":13}],
[{"po":21},{"po":22},{"po":23}]]
```

I want the result [{"po":1},{"po":11},{"po":12},{"po":13},{"po":21}]
when i call $scope.searchPo(1);

Thankyou very much

Comment: You need custom filter for this, or you may just do not use filter for this at all -- plain js or lodash or whatever.

Comment: Are you wanting to search $scope.pos or $scope.array?

Comment: @DanielWarke $scope.array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.array = [
      [{"po":1},{"po":2},{"po":3}],
      [{"po":11},{"po":12},{"po":13}],
      [{"po":21},{"po":22},{"po":23}]
    ];

    $scope.searchPo = function(id){
      return $scope.array.reduce(function(a,b){
        return a.concat($filter('filter')(b, {po: id}));
      }, []);
    }        
   
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<ul ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
   <li ng-repeat='item in searchPo(1)'>{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just write your own function, using _.filter. Here is one way of doing that

```
  var searchPo = function (arr, id) {
   var newarr = []
   var reg = new RegExp(id)
   _.filter(arr, function(value) {
     _.filter(value, function(val) {
       _.each(val, function(v) {
              //console.log(reg.test(v));
             if(reg.test(v)) {
                   newarr.push(val);
             }
       });

     });  
  });

  console.log(newarr);
};
```

var a = [[{"po":1},{"po":2},{"po":3}],[{"po":11},{"po":12},{"po":13}],
           [{"po":21},{"po":22},{"po":23}]];

searchPo(a, 1)